# insert 100 millions records to mysql database

Tags: mysql

I'm starting to learn mysql and i need a database with 100 millions records, i'm trying to use basic loop but that just takes too long. Can anyone show me how that could be done? each records can just be a number or a bit, but it has to be 100 millions

Comment: Can you share any code?

Comment: Create stored procedure which generates and saves dummy data by shunks (~10-100k rows per chunk, depends on row size). Remove triggers and disable (or remove) FK checks during generation for performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

2. CREATE TABLE my_table(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

3. INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(NULL);

4. INSERT INTO my_table SELECT NULL FROM my_table;

5. Repeat line 4 26 times.
```

Failing that, see http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2006/06/filling-test-tables-quickly.html